# MySql updating a row with data from the same table using it's parent id

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql, how can I update a row with data from the same table using its parent id?

In the example below, I'm trying to update the path of `id = 2` with the path of id = 1 (since that's it's parent) and the value of the name of `id = 2`.

What i'm trying is hopelessly wrong:

```
update paths a 
set path = (concat(select path from paths where id = parent,name)) 
where id = 2;
```

**Current**

```
"id"    "parent"    "path"          "name"
"1"     "0"         "/us/software/" "microsoft"
"2"     "1"                         "adobe"
```

**Expected**

```
"id"    "parent"    "path"                  "name"
"1"     "0"         "/us/software/"         "microsoft"
"2"     "1"         "/us/software/adobe"    "adobe"
```

take the value of path from it's parent

Comment: Have you tried grouping your sub-query? `UPDATE paths SET path = (concat((select path from paths where id = parent),name)) where id =2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE paths a
JOIN paths b ON a.parent = b.id
SET a.path = CONCAT(b.path, a.name)
WHERE a.id = 2
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e17da/1)

And my usual recommendation in situations like this: read http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/